# DOMHelpers in Angular

Tags: angular

I have faced an error in the spec file that DOMHelper cannot be found and also it cannot be imported, even though I have  imported the DOMHelper using "npm I dom-helpers" how can I fix this error, as well as ill share my screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Lms.png) Cannot find module '@testing/helpers/dom.helper' or its corresponding type declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wrote your custom path in the `tsconfig.app.json`.

Write it in `tsconfig.json` instead, or duplicate it in `tsconfig.spec.json`. Either will work.